# TPT and foreign key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have a problem with TPT inheritance + foreign key. I'm working on a web application with multi language support, including translating dynamic content. 
Here's my tables:

```
Language
=============
Id, Name


ProcessingAgent 
====================
Id, some other fields 

LocalizedProcessingAgent 
=========================================================
LocalizedProcessingAgentId, Name, Description, LanguageId
```

As you already guessed, I moved the columns which should be translated from `ProcessingAgent` to `LocalizedProcessingAgent`. On EF side, I made a TPT inheritance, so `ProcessingAgent` is a base class of `LocalizedProcessingAgent`. 
I'm new to EF, this is my first project I moved on and one of it's strange behavior really confuses me.
When I generate EF classes from DB, `LocalizedProcessingAgent` has a Navigation Property Language (Because of `LanguageId`). The problem is that `Language` property is null after I query the db:

```
LocalizedProcessingAgentRecord l = db.ProcessingAgents
    .OfType<LocalizedProcessingAgentRecord>().First(p => p.Id == 1);
//l.Language is null
```

So the foreign key Navigation Property is not filled for some reason, I don't know why.
This happens only when I query derived entities, in this case `LocalizedProcessingAgentRecord`. 
Any ideas?

here's EF xml markup: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/ef.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly load this Navigation property.

```
db.ProcessingAgents.Include("Language").OfType().First(p => p.Id == 1)
```

`Include` will result in eager loading of navigation property.

Comment: damn, should I do the same for every single query? Is there a better way to accomplish that? :(

Comment: If you are using ef v4.0 you could enable lazy loading ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnable = true. 

In ef v1.0 there is no transparent lazy loading but you can do explicit lazy loading like this: 
if(!agent.Language.IsLoaded)
agent.Language.Load();